# WPF UserControl does not update contents

Tags: wpf, user-controls, mahapps.metro

I create an Window and stylezed it with MahApps, i also created an UserControl. In my UserControl i create a method that populate some data in the UserControl elements.

In my window, i created a button that do the following:

```
EdicaoFisioterapeuta ed = new EdicaoFisioterapeuta();
ed.LoadContents("My Text");
```

when i debug the code, i see the elements of user control being populated, here is the code:

```
public void LoadContents(string text)
{
    textBox1.Text = text;
    lbl.Text = text;
}
```

After all the job, the textBox1 and the lbl does not get the content "My Text".

I create another Project and repeated the process, everything is working fine in the new project.

In my "old" project i removed MahApps, but ir doesnt get effect.

I know, it is so simple, but i cant find an solution for this trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, i was instatiating the wrong class, it seems i need to sleep a little more.